# Why one word breaks all right output in regex (perl)?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to understand the situation with regular expression in Perl.

```
$str = "123-abc 23-rr";
```

Need to show both words beside minus.
Regular expression is:

```
@mas=$str=~/(?:([\d\w]+)\-([\d\w]+))/gx;
```

And it show right output: `123`, `abc`, `23`, `rr`.
But if I change string a little and put one word in start:

```
$str = "word 123-abc 23-rr";
```

And I want to take account this first word, so I change my regexp:

```
@mas=$str=~/\w+\s(?:\s*([\d\w]+)\-([\d\w]+))*/gx;
```

My output must be same, but there are: `23`, `rr`. If I remove `\s*` or `*` the output is `123`, `abc`. But it's still not right. Anyone knows why?

Comment: You may read about *capturing repeated groups* [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

Comment: When you specify a specific beginning of input string, you can't tell engine to do a `global` match on a chunk of regex.

Comment: Also, see [Repeated Capturing and Parsing](http://blogs.perl.org/users/sirhc/2012/05/repeated-capturing-and-parsing.html). Note it is not the first `\w+` that is the "culprit", but the `*` quantifier you set on the non-capturing group.

Comment: Ok, I'll read now, hope it will decide my problem. Thanks

Comment: @revo If I right understand you, that problem in modifyer 'g'. But if remove it, output is wrong also.

Comment: Tip: `[\w\d]` can be shortened to `\w` since `\w` includes `\d`.

Comment: Sorry, no. The problem is not `g` modifier but it is the way you think and the thing you expect. Engine, simply, doesn't work like that.

Comment: @revo I understand you, my thoughts don't fit engine work, but I expect it. Need to learn better engine, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making an ever more specific regex for an ever more specific string, consider taking advantage of the overall pattern.

1. Each piece is separated by whitespace.
2. The first piece is a word.
3. The rest are pairs separated by dashes.

First split the pieces on whitespace.

```
my @pieces = split /\s+/, $str;
```

Then remove the first piece, it doesn't have to be split.

```
my $word = shift @pieces;
```

Then split each piece on `-` into pairs.

```
my %pairs = map { split /-/, $_ } @words;
```

Comment: Ok, you prefer other approach, very interesting. I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

For each match, each capture is returned.

---

In the first snippet, the pattern matches twice.

```
123-abc 23-rr
\_____/ \___/
```

There are two captures, so four (2*2=4) values are returned.

---

In the second snippet, the pattern matches once.

```
word 123-abc 23-rr
\________________/
```

There are two captures, so two (2*1=2) values are returned.

Comment: But why is 2 values? if I write (...)*, asterisk take maximum coincidences since it is greedy if I right know about it

Comment: I mean why my construction don't expand in
/\w+([\d\w]+)\-([\d\w]+)([\d\w]+)\-([\d\w]+) by engine

Comment: If that's what you want it to do, then tell it to do that. Otherwise, it will prevent people from doing `if (/(.)(?:(.)\2)*(.)/) { print $3 }`